# Why VLC not display RTP stream

Tags: h.264, vlc, rtsp, rtp, x264

I am new in RTP. I whant to start RTSP server on embeded device. Now I can whatching video file, that stored in flash memory. But when I start translate video, that encoded whith x264, VLC not display anything.
Just buffering, nothing else

```
core debug: `rtsp://172.16.50.194:1935/live1.sdp' successfully opened
core debug: Buffering 0%
packetizer_h264 debug: found NAL_SPS (sps_id=0)
core debug: Stream buffering done (11 ms in 133 ms)
core debug: Decoder wait done in 0 ms
packetizer_h264 debug: found NAL_PPS (pps_id=0 sps_id=0)
core error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR is called too late (pts_delay increased to 30 ms)
core error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
core debug: Buffering 0%
core debug: Buffering 0%
core debug: Buffering 0%
core debug: Stream buffering done (111 ms in 706 ms)
core debug: Decoder wait done in 0 ms
core error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR is called too late (pts_delay increased to 594 ms)
core error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
core debug: Buffering 0%
...
core debug: Buffering 0%
live555 warning: no data received in 10s, eof ?
core debug: EOF reached
```

That is Wireshark dump

SPS slice

```
1111 0100 = Profile_idc: Unknown (244)
0... .... = Constraint_set0_flag: 0
.0.. .... = Constraint_set1_flag: 0
..0. .... = Constraint_set2_flag: 0
...0 .... = Constraint_set3_flag: 0
.... 0... = Constraint_set4_flag: 0
.... .0.. = Constraint_set5_flag: 0
.... ..00 = Reserved_zero_2bits: 0
0000 1101 = Level_id: 13 [Level 1.3 768 kb/s]
1... .... = seq_parameter_set_id: 0
.001 00.. = log2_max_frame_num_minus4: 3
.... ..01  1... .... = pic_order_cnt_type: 2
.001 01.. = num_ref_frames: 4
.... ..1. = gaps_in_frame_num_value_allowed_flag: 1
.... ...0  10.. .... = pic_width_in_mbs_minus1: 1
..00 0001  0100 0... = pic_height_in_map_units_minus1: 39
.... .0.. = frame_mbs_only_flag: 0
.... ..0. = mb_adaptive_frame_field_flag: 0
.... ...1 = direct_8x8_inference_flag: 1
1... .... = frame_cropping_flag: 1
.1.. .... = frame_crop_left_offset: 0
..1. .... = frame_crop_left_offset: 0
...1 .... = frame_crop_top_offset: 0
.... 1... = frame_crop_bottom_offset: 0
.... .0.. = vui_parameters_present_flag: 0
.... ..1. = rbsp_stop_bit: 1
.... ...0 = rbsp_trailing_bits: 0
```

PPS slice

```
 1... .... = pic_parameter_set_id: 0
    .1.. .... = seq_parameter_set_id: 0
    ..0. .... = entropy_coding_mode_flag: 0
    ...0 .... = pic_order_present_flag: 0
    .... 1... = num_slice_groups_minus1: 0
    .... .1.. = num_ref_idx_l0_active_minus1: 0
    .... ..1. = num_ref_idx_l1_active_minus1: 0
    .... ...0 = weighted_pred_flag: 0
    00.. .... = weighted_bipred_idc: 0
    ..00 0010  110. .... = pic_init_qp_minus26(se(v)): 11
    ...1 .... = pic_init_qs_minus26: 0
    .... 1... = chroma_qp_index_offset: 0
    .... .1.. = deblocking_filter_control_present_flag: 1
    .... ..0. = constrained_intra_pred_flag: 0
    .... ...0 = redundant_pic_cnt_present_flag: 0
    1... .... = rbsp_stop_bit: 1
    .000 0000 = rbsp_trailing_bits: 0
```

And SEI

```
x264 - core 152 r2851 ba24899 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=10 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
```

What could be my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

RTSP sets up the connection using TCP - this seems to work in your case.

RTP should send audio and video using UDP - this seems to fail in your case.

```
core debug: Buffering 0%
live555 warning: no data received in 10s, eof ?
```

Your embedded device should UDP packets to VLC.
Do you see any UDP traffic from from your embedded device to VLC using Wireshark?

The SPS and PPS NAL units are part of the RTSP based setup process.

Comment: I know it, and i send data using UDP. 
I made a script on Python, that collect data from RTP packets (UDP) to raw .h264 video file and I see video on VLC. 
Why VLC may not see the data? I check UDP ports, that set in RTSP, they are correct.

Comment: Try lowering the resolution and frame rate. May be there is some packet loss.

Comment: I see on wiresharck that no loses. I send each packet every 70 ms, complite NAL unit (new IDR slice) every 500 ms and set timestamp 1s (1000*90000, frequency H264/90000). Maybe it's too slow?